# Phonegap ios InAppPurchaseManager not calling onPurchased() method

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

I am currently using the plugin

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager

for the inapppurchase in my project and in sandbox testing the iap has started and return the state as **PaymentTransactionStatePurchased** but after the alert of state(PaymentTransactionStatePurchased) the app is hanged and doesnot proceed to onPurchased() function tried a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working i was using function onDeviceReady() so it was not triggering the event for that i had to use document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady,false)